# How to set equal aspect ratio and define axis limits in plotly.js

Tags: javascript, plotly, plotly.js

I'm trying to set an equal aspect ratio AND axis limits in plotly js.

Setting the "range" of a plotly js axis is pretty trivial. E.g.

```
var layout = {
  xaxis: {range: [0, 4]}
};
```

The code [here](https://codepen.io/rsreusser/pen/ZXebXP) shows a simple example of setting the aspect ratio of a plot using schaleanchor.

However, using the two together seems to override any range set. It's possible to bypass some of this by setting width and height, but it's a bit messy. How can I automatically create an equal aspect ratio plot with defined axis ranges?